# 'My luggage is missing' or 'My luggage is lost'?

Tags: word-choice

When your luggage is minhandled at the airport, is it 'lost', 'missing' or both are correct? Now, I know that there is a subtle difference in meaning between lost and missing, but in every-day English, can both be used in that context?

Answer (score 2):

Airlines use the term **baggage handling** for loading bags onto planes. They use the term **mishandled** to describe bags that do not arrive at the correct destination, though I would not tell anybody that my bags had been [mishandled](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mishandle).

If you want to report a problem at the airport, you would say that your baggage has not arrived or is missing.

Later, you would tell your friends that the airline lost your bags.
Note that this is a transitive usage of the verb [lose](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lose), and transitive verbs may have a different meaning or usage when you use the be-verb with their past participle.

With **lose**, you generally say that a person or animal **is lost** (be-verb with past participle), meaning that they/it cannot find their/its way home. It is possible, but unusual, to use it about a thing, to mean that you can't find it. It is more common to say that a thing **got lost**.

Comment: Good answer. But use of the intransitive past participle with an inanimate object is less common. "We've lost the key" would be more usual than "Our key's got lost". The last is perhaps more used where the identification of the loser needed to be avoided. In any event I don't think, in the UK, we would use "got". If we did employ the intransitive I think it would be "It's been lost". As a general point, I believe Americans are much more fond of the words "got" and "gotten" than we are in the UK.

Comment: @WS2 "Things tend to get lost when you move."... example from Cambridge Dictionary https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lost

Comment: A very good example of where we would use "get".  Another would undoubtedly be where we told someone to "get lost". But those both employ "get" - the former in the infinitive mood, the latter the imperative. But using "got lost" as an indicative verb when speaking of an inanimate object I sense is more US that UK - that was my only point.

Comment: @WS2 There certainly are differences in usage between UK and US English for got/gotten, but they are specific to particular situations, for example a British person would ask "Have you got..." whereas an American would say "Do you have...".  If you look at actual usage, the difference between US  and UK english for "got lost" is too close to call. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+lost%3Aeng_us_2019%2Cgot+lost%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgot%20lost%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20lost%3Aeng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0

Comment: But I was just talking about the loss of inanimate objects. "I got lost on the way to the station" might be heard anywhere. But I was just suggesting that "the keys have got lost" might be heard less in Britain. But I could be wrong - it is not the biggest issue.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site!

> When your luggage is mi[s]handled at the airport, is it 'lost',
> 'missing' or both are correct?

Both are loosely correct and perfectly understandable. However, "lost" in this case tends to imply an agent who was negligent; whereas, "missing" is neutral in assigning blame or cause and so is probably the more usual expression.

Also, the expression "to be lost" tends to have the meaning "to be unable to identify one's location with respect to a desired destination," in addition to be used as a passive of "to lose."  Because of this, in talking about luggage, it would probably be slightly better to avoid saying "my baggage is lost"--which sounds like your saying that it lost its way--and should instead say "my baggage has been lost" to clearly attribute agency to someone else.

Comment: Personally, I would say that something is 'missing' while it is not possible to locate it at the time, and 'lost' when it is declared not locatable at all, ever.

Comment: At least in American English, I would be fine going up to an airport counter and saying: "My luggage got lost on my previous connection.  Do you know when you should be able to forward it to me at my hotel."

Comment: @Vegawatcher Not unique to America - "You've lost my bag" is probably the best most people manage in the circumstances short of swearing.